# How to mock a function that returns a GUID using Moq.Mock()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, vs-unit-testing-framework

How do I write a mock to a method that returns a GUID in .net mvc Unit test. eg: I have a service class which adds object to the DB and returns a GUID. I needto mock this in Unit test.

Comment: What do you think makes writing this mock any different to writing any other mocks?

Comment: In the controller I am checking if the returned GUID is not GUID.Empty. While testing it always returns empty.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.AddObject(It.IsAny<SomeObject>())))
    .Returns(Guid.NewGuid());
```